# jquery not working in the production Rails project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the development all works fine, but in the production, after deploy, not working. rake assets compilation don't help me. What should i edit ?

application.js

```
//= require es5-shim/es5-shim
//= require es5-shim/es5-shim-min
//= require es5-shim/es5-sham
//= require es5-shim/es5-sham-min
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '********' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_assets = false

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = ['*.js', '*.css']
  config.active_support.deprecation = :silence

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.log_level = :info

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of js files in the manifest file like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require es5-shim/es5-shim
//= require es5-shim/es5-shim-min
//= require es5-shim/es5-sham
//= require es5-shim/es5-sham-min
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I guess you are precompiling your assets in production mode

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: don't help(( any ideas ?